# Why should the store in redux should be a constant variable?

Tags: javascript, redux

I have seen a lot examples such as `const store = createStore(someReducer)` what's use of making it a constant when we want it to be changed through reducers? Why not var?

Comment: *"Why not var?"* There's role for `var` in modern JavaScript code. The salient question here is "Why not `let`?" ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the store will change, but you will never reassign it with another store, hence `const`.

Generally, nowadays it's usually best to use `let` and `const`, as these scope differently than `var`. `var` is not limited to block scope, so variables kind of overwrite each other in unexpected ways. Consider these two code snippets: (example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var))

```js
var x = 1;

if (x === 1) {
  var x = 2; // just changes the value of the outer variable

  console.log(x);
  // expected output: 2
}

console.log(x);
// expected output: 2
```

if you use `let` (or `const`) instead, variables exist only in the scope they are created in - shadowing each other, but not overriding each other's values:

```js
let x = 1;

if (x === 1) {
  let x = 2; // new variable with the same name for the inner block, shadows the outer variable

  console.log(x);
  // expected output: 2
}

console.log(x);
// expected output: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of `store` should never change to point to a **new** store. The *state* of the store changes, but `store` always refers to just the one store that was created. You can see that in [the `createStore` documentation's example](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore/):

> ```
> import { createStore } from 'redux'
>
> function todos(state = [], action) {
>   switch (action.type) {
>     case 'ADD_TODO':
>       return state.concat([action.text])
>     default:
>       return state
>   }
> }
>
> const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])
>
> store.dispatch({
>   type: 'ADD_TODO',
>   text: 'Read the docs'
> })
>
> console.log(store.getState())
> // [ 'Use Redux', 'Read the docs' ]
> ```

`store` never gets a new value there, but the *state* of the store it refers to changes. Notice the bit at the end getting the current state of the store.

Let's make that clearer by adding a call to `getState` **before** the `dispatch`:

```js
// console.log(Object.keys(window).sort());
const { createStore } = RTK;

function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([action.text])
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])

console.log("before dispatch:", JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
// before dispatch: ["Use Redux"]

store.dispatch({
  type: 'ADD_TODO',
  text: 'Read the docs'
})

console.log("after dispatch: ", JSON.stringify(store.getState()))
// after dispatch: ["Use Redux", "Read the docs"]
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reduxjs/toolkit"></script>
```

The *state* of the store changes, not which store is being used, so `store` never changes.

Answer (score 1):

`const` does not create an immutable data structure, it [just prevents that variable from being reassigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

```js
const numbers = [1,2,3];

// mutating the object assigned to `numbers` is fine
numbers.push(4);

// reassigning the variable is not
numbers = [1,2,3,4];
```

Generally, `const` is used where a variable will not be reassigned, and where block scoping is desirable. The redux store object is a great example of that.